Set property type
Is it possible to set the type of a property in TypeScript without casting it? Consider this code:
interface Overlay {
    type: "modal" | "drawer"
    other?: number
}

const rec = {
    obj1: { type: "modal" },
    obj2: { type: "drawer" },
    ...
}

The object rec has the type { obj1: { type: string }, obj2: { type: string } }. I want it to have the type { obj1: Overlay, obj2: Overlay, ... }.
My attempts:

Ok - but very verbose and adds variables

const obj1: Overlay = { type: "modal" }
const obj2: Overlay = { type: "drawer" }
const ...
const rec = { obj1, obj2, ... }


Bad - allows errors to be hidden (e.g. {} as Overlay will be considered ok by TS). Using satisfies instead does not set the type, just checks it on a per-property basis.

const rec = {
    obj1: { type: "modal" } as Overlay,
    obj2: { type: "drawer" } as Overlay,
    ...
}


Bad - loses the key type information ("obj1" | "obj2" | ... becomes string)

const rec: Record<string, Overlay> = {
    obj1: { type: "modal" },
    obj2: { type: "drawer" },
    ...
}


Bad - loses information about the 'other' property and incorrectly sets the type of 'type' to either "modal" or "drawer" instead of the union type

const rec = {
    obj1: { type: "modal" },
    obj2: { type: "drawer" },
    ...
} as const

Is there a better way to achieve the correct type than #1?

You can't control inference in such detail (you don't want to keep track of the particular subtype of Overlay of the properties but you do want to keep track of the particular set of keys) without some more machinery. If a helper function is acceptable then you can write one and then it will infer in exactly the way you want, as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Record
You can use the Record type for this, like so:
type AcceptedKey = 'obj1' | 'obj2' | 'obj3'

interface Overlay {
  type: 'modal' | 'drawer'
  other?: number
}

const rec: Record<AcceptedKey, Overlay> = {
  obj1: { type: 'modal' },
  obj2: { type: 'drawer' },
  obj3: { type: 'drawer' },
}

Objects passed to each property of the "Record" will now have to match the Overlay type. Also, each item from AcceptedKey must exist as a key in the Record.
The spec of Record is as follows:

 /**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};


Partial Record
If you also want the AcceptedKey to be used as optional keys you can use Partial in conjunction with Record like so:
const partialRec: Partial<Record<AcceptedKey, Overlay>> = {
  obj1: { type: 'modal' },
  obj2: { type: 'drawer' },
}

This can be a good option if you have a finite and predetermined amount of keys.
Key format instead of specific keys
If you need the type of the key to a format rather than concrete values you can embed a number type into a string type like so:
type AcceptedKeyFormat = `obj${number}`

interface Overlay {
  type: 'modal' | 'drawer'
  other?: number
}

const rec2: Record<AcceptedKeyFormat, Overlay> = {
  obj0: { type: 'modal' },
  obj1: { type: 'drawer' },
  obj999: { type: 'drawer' },
}

This also means you do not have to add every key to the type as well. This can be a good option if each record may have different keys.

This is explicitly listed as “bad” #3 in the question

Thanks. You can replace string with a custom type that holds "obj1" | "obj2" | "obj3". Edited the answer to reflect this.

Okay, but now it's not dynamic in the keys, which seems to be the point? It's hard to tell though, I guess we'll see what OP says.

Agreed. In the meantime I've added a case for having an accepted key format instead of concrete values for the key type.

I'm looking for a method that is (a) not verbose and (b) not prone to errors. I think (b) applies to this one, as  you will get errors if extra keys are added to the object but not to AcceptedKeys (or the other way around). You'd still have to repeat the key names but it is better than the variables method.

@Chaoz These errors you're referring to will show up immediately in the linter. That's the whole point of TypeScript: finding bugs before deploying your code. It is exactly the way you'd want to interact with TypeScript. Either way you could also use AcceptedKeyFormat as the last paragraph in this answer suggests. I do not think there is a less verbose way, but will follow the question to be proven wrong.
